# Keycloak Support for JWE & Opaque for Access Token and Refresh Token

Tags: keycloak

I would like to know whether Keycloak supports JWE or Opaque Tokens for access or refresh token. Documentation suggests that jwe is supported for id token but not sure for access and refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Opaque tokens are not supported in current versions of Keycloak.

Access and refresh [issue](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5290#:%7E:text=Description,Support%20with%20a%20global%20secret.) was closed with resolution *Won't do*.

However, there is a [PoC project](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-keycloak-jwe-example) available in Github (albeit for older versions) by Thomas Darimont, the maintainer of the Keycloak.